# Is it possible to define the usage of bits in the DataContract of a WCF service?

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, datacontract, wcf-serialization

I have a C++ program with a typical mode `int` that uses a bitmask. This bitmask is defined in an enum like this:

```
enum EModeEntryPoint
{
    // Mode
    entryPointNone              =0x00,
    entryPointNormal            =0x01,
    entryPointExistingAddress   =0x02,
    entryPointNewAddress        =0x04,
    entryPointNewAndExisting    =0x06,  
    entryPointOnlyNewTickets    =0x08,  
};
```

When I use an enum in a C# WCF service like this

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public enum ModeEntryPoint
{
    // Mode
    [EnumMember] None              =0x00,
    [EnumMember] Normal            =0x01,
    [EnumMember] ExistingAddress   =0x02,
    [EnumMember] NewAddress        =0x04,
    [EnumMember] NewAndExisting    =0x06,  
    [EnumMember] OnlyNewTickets    =0x08,  
};
```

I can see that the values I define here, are not used. I can see that such enums are always "renumbered".

Is it possible to define such bit-usage in the contract anywhere?

Creating a bool field for each bit isn't what I like. Also it bloats the data block.

Comment: do you want to use `DataContract` or `DataContractAttribute` ?

Comment: I think you should be specifying the enum values, e.g. `[EnumMember(Value="ExistingAddress")]`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks. I will look at this!

Comment: also: if those are bits: consider marking the enum with `[Flags]`; it may also be useful to consider `None = 0`, `Normal = 1 << 0`, `ExistingAddress = 1 << 1`, `NewAddress = 1 << 2`, `NewAndExisting = NewAddress | ExistingAddress`

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/enumeration-types-in-data-contracts?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and find some solution.

Comment: The [Flags] keyword is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [Flags] keyword is the solution.

```
[DataContractAttribute][Flags]
public enum ModeEntryPoint
{
    // Mode
    [EnumMember] None = 0x00,
    [EnumMember] Normal = 0x01,
    [EnumMember] ExistingAddress = 0x02,
    [EnumMember] NewAddress = 0x04,
    [EnumMember] 
    NewAndExisting = ExistingAddress| NewAddress,  
    [EnumMember] OnlyNewTickets = 0x08,  
};
```

This allows the WCF client to deocde the specific fields of this type.